# C# Accessing classes in a WinForms project from a classes in a Class Library

Tags: c#-4.0

I have two c# projects within a solution.

The first project is a `winforms` project with several classes and is called `QuantumGUI`. The second project is a `class library` project with several classes and is called `QuantumDAL`.

My objective is from a class in QuantumDAL to access and set variables in a QuantumGUI class or and in Form.cs.
I have tried adding a reference to QuantumGUI in my QuantumDAL project but received the following error: `“A Reference to ‘QuantumGUI’ could not be added. Adding the project as a reference would cause a circular dependency”.`
  I received a similar error message trying to add Project Dependencies. When you think about it, the error message makes sense.
I’ve tried other, what I consider possible ways of doing this but came up empty. I believe there must be a clever way of getting this done.
If I’m going about this in a wrong way, is there a way to have a “global” class that can be accessed by code in both projects?
Thank you for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: What you're proposing sounds like bad design to start with. Generally each layer should only know about the layer *below* it, not vice versa. Your GUI should *ask* for the values, or register event handlers to receive updated information. Why would a class library want to tie itself to a particular UI?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with what you're trying to do:

First, as the IDE is warning you, you're about to create a circular dependency. This means that the compiler would need to build project A before it can build project B, but it would need to build project B before it can build project A. Neither project can go "first".

The second problem is that your WinForms project is most likely an executable, and you cannot add references to `*.exe` files via the IDE. You can add those references via the command-line, but the fact that Visual Studio is trying to stop you from doing it should be a red flag that it's a really bad idea.

The correct way to do what you want is to refactor the common classes into a third class library that you reference from both other projects. If needed, you can wire up events (in particular, look at the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms133020.aspx) interface and its event) that notify interested observer objects when things change.